# I dont know why but when I run the following code it return 9 as a prime number

Tags: python

Im supposed to make a function that takes an integer and returns if its a prime or not but for some reason it returns 9 as a prime

```
def prime(x):
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return "not prime"
    elif x == 2:
           return "prime"
    else:
      for numbers in range(2,x):
       if x % numbers == 0:
            return "not prime"
       else:
            return "prime"

for i in range(20):
    print (i, prime(i))
```

Comment: `else:
        return "prime"` happens when `numbers` is 2, at first iteration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first numbers are either even or prime.

9 is the first number where the bug in your code really shows.

The bug is: you return "prime" if *one test* fails. Since `9 % 2` is not 0, the test fails there.

rewrite (naively) as:

```
  for numbers in range(2,x):
     if x % numbers == 0:
          return "not prime"
  return "prime"
```

so if the loop ends without returning the number is prime.

Note that there are better & faster ways to test primality. For instance, don't loop up to `x-1` but to square root of `x` (included), since there can't exist divisors after that value.

```
 for numbers in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return an answer on the first iteration, at which point it stops iterating:

```
for numbers in range(2,x):
  if x % numbers == 0:
    return "not prime"
  else:
    return "prime"
```

This starts with 2, and if it goes into x evenly, it returns not prime, if not it returns prime, and either way it stops.

```
for numbers in range(2,x):
  if x % numbers == 0:
    return "not prime"
return "prime"
```

This would do the trick, though, as it will only return "prime" if none of the numbers returned "not prime".